# Tensor products and sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, direct-sum

We know that tensor product commutes with direct sum. I am wondering if tensor product commutes with sum (or finite sum.)

I.e.) $N\bigotimes (\sum M_i)=\sum(N\otimes M_i)$

$N,M_i$ are $A$ module. ($A$ is commutative ring with unit)

I couldn't find a counter example. Please lead me to find one (if the statement is wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Tensor products are [left adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) to taking homs, and so they commute with arbitrary colimits. In particular

$$N \otimes \left ( \sum M_\alpha \right ) = \sum (N \otimes M_\alpha)$$

I'm sure there is a more pedestrian way to see this as well, but as some pople say: "category theory exists to make obvious things obviously obvious". I think this is a good example of that principle in action!

After searching, I found [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563727/tensor-product-and-direct-sum) that avoids abstract nonsense.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Oh , I skipped direct limits exercise in atiyah MD. Now, for last several hour I was stuck in some problem.  And it seems this is crucial step. Now I think I will do all the skipped problems asa I find time. I also wanna study Category theory, hopefully I do it in this summer. Thanks your help.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have only 10 days vacation for this winter due to corona, not sure if I can do reasonable amount in 10 days.  But as you mention, now I think I will start it and then do as much as possible.

Comment: at HallaSurvivor @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. $\bigoplus M_\alpha$ is the direct sum of the $M_\alpha$. It is a different notation for the same object ^_^

Comment: Sum and direct sum are not same , then how it is same object?