# $\mathbb{R}[x] \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

In class we went over tensor products of vector spaces. I'm still a bit confused about this and just wanted to check that I understand it concretely. For example if $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with real coefficients it is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Also $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. We can construct $\mathbb{R}[x] \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2$. I kinda get the abstract definition but what I'm trying to see is if I understand it more concretely. So for example if I take the polynomial $2 + 3x$ and the vector $(5,7)$ I think that $(2 + 3x) \otimes (5,7)$ is the same as the vector $(10+15x, 14 + 21x)$. Is this correct?
If this is correct then

> is $\mathbb{R}[x] \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2$ the same as the set of all pairs $(f(x), g(x))$ where $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and they differ just by a constant factor in $\mathbb{R}$ or in other words $f(x) = a g(x)$ for some real number $a$?

Comment: Not quite. Remember that the tensor product is a vector space, so you can add any two vectors also. Therefore for all polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ we get that the combo
$$f(x)\otimes(1,0)+g(x)\otimes (0,1)$$ is in there. In the spirit of your bilinear mapping from $\Bbb{R}[x]\times \Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}[x]^2$ we see that the above combo maps to $(f(x),0)+(0,g(x))=(f(x),g(x))$. In other words
$$\Bbb{R}[x]\otimes_{\Bbb{R}}\Bbb{R}^2\simeq \Bbb{R}[x]^2.$$

Comment: My favorite example when teaching tensor products is the observation
$$\Bbb{R}[x]\otimes_{\Bbb{R}}\Bbb{R}[x]\simeq \Bbb{R}[x,y].$$ The underlying bilinear mapping being $(f(x),g(x))\mapsto f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: Your description covers only the objects like $f(x)\otimes (a,b)$ that are often called elementary tensors. But the tensor product as a space is bigger.

Comment: Oooh I see!! I forgot that we can add things together. So $\mathbb{R}[x] \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2$ is all the the pairs $(f(x),g(x))$ where $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensor products and sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924141/tensor-products-and-sum) (apply it to $N=\Bbb R[x]$ and $M_1=M_2=\Bbb R$)