# What about the algebraic structure of $T_p(G) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p}A$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

Let $G$ be a $p$-divisible group over the ring of $p$-adic integers $O_K$ of $p$-adic field $K$.

The $p$-adic Tate  module $T_p(G)$ of $G$ is rank $1$ free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module.

Then $T_p(G) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Let $A$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra, then consider the tensor product $T_p(G) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p}A$.

**My question:**

What about the algebraic structure of $T_p(G) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p}A$ ?

$(1)$ Is it a free $A$-module ?

$(2)$ Can we think of $T_p(G) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p}A$  as a Galois representation of some suitable Galois group?

Any help with two questions.

**Edit:**  For $(2)$, one exmaple is as follows: If $G$ is the abelian group of roots of unity in a separable closure $K^s$ of $K$,then the $p$-adic Tate module $T_p(G)$ is equipped with linear action of the absolute Galois group of $K$  or $T_p(G)$ is the Galois representation or more specifically, $p$-adic cyclotomic character.

But what about if $G$ is the$p$-divisible group ?

Comment: For a Galois representation, one should have a Galois group. As stated, (2) is a meaningless question; I can of course think of anything as a representation with respect to the trivial action. To say something meaningful, one should at least have some candidate of an action of some Galois group on our object, right?

Comment: And re (1), in your first intro to tensor products over rings, you should have learned that for any scalar extension $R \rightarrow S$, and $M$ a free $R$-module, we have that $M\otimes_R S$ is a free $S$-module; and why that is (tensor product commutes with direct sums). As a refresher, look here (and you only need the easy case of *finite* direct sum): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563727/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, ok,  I left the options open in $(2)$. For example, the $p$-adic Tate  module of the abelian group of roots of unity in a separable closure $K^s$ of $K$  is a rank one free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module equipped with linear action of the absolute Galois group of $K$. In this case $T_p(G)$ is a Galois representation or $p$-adic cyclotomic character. That is why I left the option in $(2)$ open

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, and thanks for the answer for the first question.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}_p$ vector spaces aren't free $\Bbb{Z}_p$ modules. Why don't you try making concrete your $T_p(G)$ built from roots of unity?

Comment: @reuns, ahh, my mistake. Ofcourse $\mathbb{Q}$ is not free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I corrected my question.