# Tensor - sum distributivity with common index

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, direct-sum

I am well aware of the [distributivity of tensor product over direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563727/tensor-product-and-direct-sum) for $R$-modules over a commutative ring. I see how  it works for direct sums and tensor products of the form

$$(\oplus_\alpha M_\alpha)\otimes N\cong \oplus_\alpha (M_\alpha\otimes N)$$

However, what happens if $N$ is also a direct sum depending on $\alpha$? For instance, let $M=\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}}M_\alpha$ and similarly $N=\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}}N_\alpha$. Consider the following direct sum of tensor products for a fixed integer $k$:

$$\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}} (M_\alpha\otimes N_{k-\alpha})$$

If I had independent indices for $M$ and $N$ I could simply use the above isomorphism and the analogue on the right to write the sum of tensor products as a tensor product of sums, obtaining something like

$$(\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}} M_\alpha)\otimes (\oplus_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}} N_{\beta})$$ But in this case, $\beta=k-\alpha$, so it doesn't seem to make sense to write the tensor in that way. If I wrote

$$(\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}} M_\alpha)\otimes (\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}} N_{k-\alpha})$$
each $\alpha$ is free, so $k-\alpha$ would take any value independently of the value of the $\alpha$ in the left factor.

Is there a way I can write the sum

$$\oplus_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}} (M_\alpha\otimes N_{k-\alpha})$$

as tensor product of sums? Or some way of using distributivity in this case?

Comment: Forget about modules. Imagine those are good old numbers. Can you write this sum $\sum_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} m_i\cdot n_{k-i}$ as a product of sums?

Comment: I don't think I can because it looks like $\cdots+m_0\cdot n_k+m_1\cdot n_{k-1}+\cdots$, so it doesn't look like there is anything to group

Comment: I forgot to mention you @CaptainLama

Comment: Slightly different question, but if I have the independent indices $\sum_i\sum_j m_i\cdot m_j$, I can introduce a new index to write this as $\sum_k\sum_{i+j=k}m_i\cdot n_j$ right? Because it is just grouping those whose indices have the  same sum

Comment: Yes, you can. For modules, you can define $M=\bigoplus M_n$ and $N = \bigoplus N_n$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-graded modules, and then $M\otimes N$ is also a naturally $\mathbb{Z}$-graded module, with its grade $k$ piece being precisely $\bigoplus_{i+j=k} M_i\otimes N_j$.